# NSUserDefauls BOOL Value is not set in iOS

Tags: ios

Although the code for NSUserDefaults seems quite simple I cannot make it work.

I have a settingViews where user can disable the sound or not. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.soundSettings.font = [UIFont rw_snapFontWithSize:24.0f];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"stateForSoundSwitch"]) {
        NSLog(@"Sound is ON");
        self.soundStatus.on=YES;
    } else {
        self.soundStatus.on=NO;
        NSLog(@"Sound is OFF");
    }
}

- (IBAction)soundSwitchChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (self.soundStatus.on) {
        NSLog(@"Sound is enabled");
        [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"stateForSoundSwitch"];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sound is disabled");
        [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"stateForSoundSwitch"];
    }
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

But even if I change the switch to FALSE, every time I log in the settings screen the value is TRUE. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setBool:forKey: expects a BOOL. Try using YES or NO instead of true or false (which is type bool, lowercase).

Also you should access it with boolForKey instead of objectForKey.

Your logic test will always be YES if you've ever set the object in NSUserDefaults since you're effectively testing if the key exists (i.e. not nil), not whether it is actually set to YES/NO.

In other words, change:

`if ([defaults objectForKey:@"stateForSoundSwitch"]) {`

to this:

```
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"stateForSoundSwitch"] == YES) {
```

Comment: Although this is conceptually right, there's a 99.995% chance they are the very same.

Comment: Worked with boolForKey.